# Copy rows to a new sheet using command button

Tags: excel, vba, commandbutton

I am attempting to use a command button to copy rows to a different sheet in my excel workbook. I hope to type in the row number and have the VBA copy the row into a worksheet called "6.2022 Basis". My issue is "6.2022 Basis" has over 150 rows and my previous codes have overwritten some rows that I need. I am trying to use rngToCopy but I keep getting errors. Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim rngToCopy As Range

Dim rngToPaste As Range

Set rngToCopy = Application.InputBox("Select range in Updates", Type:=64)

Windows("6.2022 Basis").Activate

Set rngToPaste = Application.InputBox("Select range to Paste in 6.2022 Basis", Type:=64)

rngToCopy.Copy

rngToPaste.Activate

ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

End Sub
```

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim rngToCopy As Range

Dim rngToPaste As Range

Set rngToCopy = Application.InputBox("Select range in Updates", Type:=8)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("6.2022 Basis").Activate

Set rngToPaste = Application.InputBox("Select range to Paste in 6.2022
Basis", Type:=8)

rngToCopy.Copy

rngToPaste.Activate

ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

End Sub

I think the new issue is I need to paste the row in a table for my sort functions to work, and then it tries to overwrite the cell.

Comment: What errors do you get? Which line of code is highlighted when the error occurs?

Comment: I get Run Time error '9": Subscript out of range, it highlights Windows("6.2022 Basis").Activate  The row that I am selecting is A:R if that could be part of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. InputBox [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox#remarks) 64 is an array of values. If you're trying to save the ranges, you need to set Type = 8.
2. For worksheets, use the `Thisworkbook.Worksheets` or `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` collection instead of the `Application.Windows` collection. If you have a second workbook that you are working on, you can also use `WB.Worksheets` where WB is any valid workbook object. Same as before, you can reference the worksheet by name or by number: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("6.2022 Basis").Activate`
3. Pasting data onto a table causes an error with `Link:=True`. You will need to switch methods from using `Worksheet.Paste` to directly assigning the values & formulas, cell by cell. I would suggest using a loop like the following:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim rngToCopy As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rngToCopy = Application.InputBox("Select range in Updates", Type:=8)
If rngToCopy Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("6.2022 Basis").Activate

Dim rngToPaste As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rngToPaste = Application.InputBox("Select range to Paste in 6.2022 Basis", Type:=8)
If rngToPaste Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0

rngToPaste.ClearContents

Dim r As Long, c As Long
For r = 1 To rngToCopy.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To rngToCopy.Columns.Count
        If rngToCopy.Cells(r, c) <> "" Then
            rngToPaste.Cells(r, c).Formula = "=" & rngToCopy.Cells(r, c).Address(External:=True)
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got a run-time error. So I tried 64 both didn't work.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim rngToPaste As Range

    Set rngToCopy = Application.InputBox("Select range in Updates", Type:=8)

    Windows("6.2022 Basis.xlsm").Activate

    Set rngToPaste = Application.InputBox("Select range to Paste in 6.2022 Basis", Type:=8)

    rngToCopy.Copy

    rngToPaste.Activate

    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

End Sub

Comment: Like this? I just ran this and I got the same error "Run-time error '9'"

Comment: Is your file named "6.2022 Basis.xlsm" ? Or is one of the worksheets named "6.2022 Basis"? A Window is when you open a file to view it, a worksheet is one of the tabs inside that file.

Comment: I am copying from "Updates" to "6.2022 Basis" in my workbook. They are both worksheets, sorry!

Comment: HI, changing to  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("6.2022 Basis").Activate   Worked!!! Now I'm getting Run-time error '1004' after the row has been copied.

Comment: @JuliaWalker Please edit your post and add your current code (after these changes). add it underneath your first block of code. That way I can see what else might be causing problems.

Comment: The new code worked, but I need the info in the cell it cleared. Is it possible to add a row in the table for the copied row to go into?

Comment: @jmowalker This sounds like the perfect time to start a new post with the new questions you have now that this one is solved.